# professional development questions - SO? Or elsewhere?

Tags: questions, discussion

I am sorting out some professional development stuff at the moment(software engineering/computer science is the profession, of course), and I want to ask questions about it.

I'm not sure SO is the right place though, such questions seem to fall into grey areas. Is there a better place in the stack exchange world, or... ?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of questions you want to ask?

Comment: @Peter: "What sites are important to have accounts on: e.g., linkedin/twitter/etc?", "What are good 'job boards' for contract telecommute programming work?". Basically I'm looking forward in time to graduation and laying groundwork so I have a better chance at a job  then. :-)

Comment: Those aren't programming questions at all.

Comment: @random: No, they are not coding questions. But they are most definitely questions that relate to me as a working programmer. The meta question here is, *do they relate enough to ask on SO*.

Comment: @Paul: they're not coding questions *or* programming questions. And... they're "list" questions, which are kinda problematic on SO-type sites in any case. That said, you might want to give http://advice.personforce.com/ a shot; it appears to be just getting off the ground, but could prove a good fit...

Comment: @shog9: Interesting site. Thank you. I'll see if anyone can help me out!

Answer (score 7):

Think about it this way:  if you were posting the question to a general forum where *anything* was allowed, would you naturally tag the question as `programming`, or something else?

For this case, I imagine that *most* professional development questions would naturally be tagged something like `professional-development` (or `careers`) and `programmer`.  Note that "programmer" is ***not*** the same thing as "programming".  There needs to be something that ties the question to "programming" (the activity), not just "programmers" (people) or "programming" (the profession).

Comment: +1; programmer-related != programming-related.

Comment: @Smurfsorting Farfulburger:  That's not a universally accepted truth; I won't vote to close a programmer-related question as long as it's a real programmer-related question.  If the question would relate to accountants as well, though, I vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

If they're programming-related (your development *as a career programmer*), and you can ask direct, answerable questions... then SO is The Place.

Otherwise, see: [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)

(A common pitfall for career questions on SO is that many, at their core, have nothing to do with programming. Plenty of the problems that you'll face are the same for accountants, engineers, drafters, etc...)

#### See also:

The [List of StackExchange Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites)